# Why is Cat 5 only specified to 100Mhz?

Tags: ethernet, cables

Why is Cat 5 cable only specified up to 100Mhz, if it's to be used for 100BASE-TX, which surely contains frequencies much higher than 100Mhz?

Likewise, why is Cat 6A only specified to 500Mhz, but is suitable for 10GBASE-T?

Comment: Some useful links: [Ethernet physical layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_physical_layer), [Ethernet over twisted pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_over_twisted_pair), [Physical Coding Sublayer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Coding_Sublayer), and lastly [PAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse_amplitude_modulation).

Comment: And also [Cat 5 cable 100Mhz bandwidth meaning](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/277313/cat-5-cable-100mhz-bandwidth-meaning)

Comment: In summary: 100MHz for Cat 5 is what the spec says it needs to be. For 100BASE-TX 31.25MHz is the worst case bandwidth requirement for MLT-3 (the signalling scheme used).